# JackRabbit OAK: Idle DB transactions are getting generated in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

We are using JackRabbit OAK implementation in our Project with postgresql DB integration. Below is the code snippets for repository creation using postgresql.

```
    private static Repository createRepo(final Map<String, String> dbDetails)
                                                                          throws DataStoreException {
    try {
        final RDBOptions options =
            new RDBOptions().tablePrefix(dbDetails.get(DB_TABLE_PREFIX)).dropTablesOnClose(
                false);
        final DataSource ds =
            RDBDataSourceFactory.forJdbcUrl(
                dbDetails.get("db_URL"),
                dbDetails.get("db_User"),
                dbDetails.get("db_Password"));
        final Properties properties = buildS3Properties(dbDetails);
        final S3DataStore s3DataStore = buildS3DataStore(properties);
        final DataStoreBlobStore dataStoreBlobStore = new DataStoreBlobStore(s3DataStore); // NOSONAR
        final Whiteboard wb = new DefaultWhiteboard();
        bapRegistration =
            wb.register(
                BlobAccessProvider.class,
                (BlobAccessProvider) dataStoreBlobStore,
                properties);
        documentNodeStore =
            new RDBDocumentNodeStoreBuilder()
                .setBlobStore(dataStoreBlobStore)
                .setBundlingDisabled(true)
                .setRDBConnection(ds, options)
                .build();
        repository = new Jcr(documentNodeStore).with(wb).createRepository();
        return repository;
    } catch (final DataStoreException e) {
        log.error("Error." + e);
        throw new DataStoreException("Error");
    }
}
```

Our application is running fine, but when we are checking postgresql DB statistics, we could see lots of idle or idle in transactions connection are getting created at DB end.

```
 xxxxx | 6 days 05:56:12.75259   | select ID, MODIFIED, MODCOUNT, CMODCOUNT, HASBINARY, DELETEDONCE, VERSION, SDTYPE, SDMAXREVTIME, DATA, BDATA from mango_NODES where SDTYPE in ($1, $2, $3)  and SDMAXREVTIME <= $4 and VERSION >= $5 | idle in transaction
 xxxxx | 5 days 22:05:38.855597  | select ID, MODIFIED, MODCOUNT, CMODCOUNT, HASBINARY, DELETEDONCE, VERSION, SDTYPE, SDMAXREVTIME, DATA, BDATA from mango_NODES where DELETEDONCE = $1 and MODIFIED < $2 and MODIFIED >= $3            | idle in transaction
 xxxxx | 25 days 23:02:38.845462 | SET application_name = 'PostgreSQL JDBC Driver'                                                                                                                                                      | idle
 xxxxx | 25 days 23:02:38.829477 | SET application_name = 'PostgreSQL JDBC Driver'                                                                                                                                                      | idle
 xxxxx | 5 days 06:21:58.12896   | COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                                               | idle
 xxxxx | 6 days 15:15:29.972181  | select ID, MODIFIED, MODCOUNT, CMODCOUNT, HASBINARY, DELETEDONCE, VERSION, SDTYPE, SDMAXREVTIME, DATA, BDATA from mango_NODES where SDTYPE in ($1, $2, $3)  and SDMAXREVTIME <= $4 and VERSION >= $5 | idle in transaction
 xxxxx | 6 days 19:27:06.133048  | select ID, MODIFIED, MODCOUNT, CMODCOUNT, HASBINARY, DELETEDONCE, VERSION, SDTYPE, SDMAXREVTIME, DATA, BDATA from mango_NODES where DELETEDONCE = $1 and MODIFIED < $2 and MODIFIED >= $3            | idle in transaction
 xxxxx | 6 days 12:17:47.585068  | select ID, MODIFIED, MODCOUNT, CMODCOUNT, HASBINARY, DELETEDONCE, VERSION, SDTYPE, SDMAXREVTIME, DATA, BDATA from mango_NODES where DELETEDONCE = $1 and MODIFIED < $2 and MODIFIED >= $3            | idle in transaction
 xxxxx | 1 day 20:54:32.433188   | SET application_name = 'PostgreSQL JDBC Driver'

postgres xxxxx  4210  1 Nov18 ?        01:51:26 postgres: main: cms cms_prod 10.x.x.x(xxxxx) idle in transaction
postgres xxxxx  4210  0 Nov18 ?        00:42:05 postgres: main: cms cms_prod 10.x.x.x(xxxxx) idle in transaction
postgres xxxxx  4210  3 Nov18 ?        06:18:13 postgres: main: cms cms_prod 10.x.x.x(xxxxx) idle
postgres xxxxx  4210  3 Nov18 ?        05:46:57 postgres: main: cms cms_prod 10.x.x.x(xxxxx) idle
postgres xxxxx  4210  0 Nov18 ?        00:24:22 postgres: main: cms cms_prod 10.x.x.x(xxxxx) idle in transaction
postgres xxxxx  4210  0 Nov18 ?        00:08:08 postgres: main: cms cms_prod 10.x.x.x(xxxxx) idle in transaction
postgres xxxxx  4210  0 Nov18 ?        00:27:06 postgres: main: cms cms_prod 10.x.x.x(xxxxx) idle in transaction
postgres xxxxx  4210  0 Nov17 ?        00:00:00 postgres: main: cms cms_prod 10.xx.xxx.xx(xxxxx) idle
```

How to avoid this idle connections in JackRabbit oak implementation?
Can we directly kill those idle connections?

Comment: Sessions that are `idle` are not a problem, but `idle in transaction` is if they stay in that state for a long time. This is almost always a bug in the application not committing transactions properly.

Comment: This looks as if background garbage collection tasks are not properly finishing..

Comment: @JulianReschke It might be a issue because recently we have started running GC using MarkSweepGarbageCollector and VersionGarbageCollection. Some of the run of GC is getting failed due to space issue or documents exceeded beyond 100000. 

Does Jackrabbit oak has provision to configure automatic closing of idle connections in such scenario without impacting to running repository.

Comment: Optimally, the GC should succeed. If it doesn't, that should be investigated. That said, if it does fail, the code should properly close all transactions. If it does not, this might be a (minor) bug.

Comment: @JulianReschke I could see JackRabbit Oak internally handles and have control over all the transactions happens during GC run. Is there any method implemented in GC classes/interfaces to handle/configure DB transactions in case of error scenario?

Comment: No, GC is not specific to relational data bases.

I would recommend that you try to reproduce the issue, see whether the log file contains more information, and open a ticket over at <https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/OAK>